# Importing stata files into R and variables have to be filtered using labels and not actual numerical values

Tags: r, import

I have a very basic question on importing STATA files into R, and I tried searching the forum but could not find what I was looking for.

I have a DHS file (AR - HIV test results) and it only has several fields as follows, after importing into R using the foreign package:

```
    AR_HIV_dataset <- read.dta("RWAR71FL.DTA") #HIV test result file
```

My question is on how to filter some cases with dplyr based on the value of a variable e.g. HIV03. Using the structure command, the variable HIV03 is displayed as "HIV negative", "HIV  positive", etc:

$ hiv03   : Factor w/ 8 levels "hiv negative",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

but the actual data values stored are just 0 or 1. However, I cannot refer to these numerical values as the filter command seems to need me to specify the label values, e.g.

```
    filter(AR_HIV_dataset,hiv03=="hiv negative")
```

this will return the required cases, but I would like to be able to use the following command instead (using the actual values)

```
    filter(AR_HIV_dataset, hiv03==0)
```

But if I do that,this returns an error.

Can you let me know what I need to change in order to use the second line of code instead?

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Comment: Hi, can you provide an output illustrating the following statement **"...but the actual data values stored are just 0 or 1"**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try the haven package may be that might be a solution.

Comment: Dear markdly, thanks - I used haven instead and it worked as the column hiv03 now displays the values 0 or 1 rather than "hiv negative", "hiv...", etc.  Many thanks.  I cannot find a button to vote this answer? thanks again

Comment: thanks for the tip on forum rules @markdly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `haven` package (http://haven.tidyverse.org/) to import the stata file may be helpful especially if you are using `dplyr` given both packages are part of the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/).  The [vignette on semantics](http://haven.tidyverse.org/articles/semantics.html) may be particularly useful when looking at how variables in stata etc are treated when imported into R.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions are:

```
filter(AR_HIV_dataset, as.numeric(hiv03)==0)
```

Or, somewhat nicer

```
filter(AR_HIV_dataset, hiv03 == levels( hiv03 )[1] )
```

Comment: thank you for your kind response. I tried it but it does not seem to work however.

Comment: Thanks very much user 429791,I tried this but did not work (I did not explain myself well I don't think), but I found a solution using haven now so let's see then. Thanks again.